# Mongodb updateone with $set and $currentDate throws error code 40 after second update

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using node and mongodb, and I want to update a document and add the date of modification. I am having a problem when I update for the second time. The specific case of failing on the second time is because:

- the document already exists but doesn't have a 'lastModified' field.
- first time modification adds the 'lastModified' field with the correct value.
- second time modification has to update the 'lastModified' field with the current date but fails.

The error shown is:

> {"driver":true,"name":"MongoError","index":0,"code":40,"errmsg":"Updating the path 'lastModified' would create a conflict at 'lastModified'"},"params":null}}

the document in mongo is:

```
{
    _id" : ObjectId("5af07316fc5f13c574ba825b"),
    "field1" : "value1"
}
```

my code for updating is:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert');

let url = 'some mongo url';
let database = 'some database';
let newData = {'field1':'newValue1'}

(async function() {
    let client;
    try {
        client = await MongoClient.connect(url , {useNewUrlParser: true});
        let database = client.db(database);
        let result = await database.collection(collection).updateOne(filter, {
                $set: newData,
                $currentDate: {'lastModified': true}
            });

        assert.equal(1, result.matchedCount);
        assert.equal(1, result.modifiedCount);

        // Close connection
        client.close();
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.stack);
    }

    // Close connection
    client.close();
})();
```

After the first update, the document in the db is:

```
{
    _id" : ObjectId("5af07316fc5f13c574ba825b"),
    "field1" : "value1",
    "lastModified" : ISODate("2018-09-07T23:18:21.485Z")
}
```

Which is correct.
The second time I try to update, it fails.

I'm using:

```
"mongodb": "^3.1.4",
"node": "^10.10.0",
```

Any suggestions on what can possibly be wrong?

**Edit:**

After the first update, the data is taken from the database, and then the second update is executed.

Comment: Sounds like `newData` in your `$set` includes the `lastModified` field from the previous set. You cannot have a `$set` and `$currentDate` on the same field. Remove `lastModified` from `newData` before updating.

Comment: @Greg you are right, added that info to the question. Basically I have to check before if I am updating if that field is in the data to be updated? is there a mongo update operator or an option in the currentDate that will let me do this without modifying the newData obj?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is thrown because the object in $set contains a property that will also be set by $currentDate. The solution is to make sure that the property doesn't exist in newData if it will be set by any [update operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/).

In this case, before the update, clean newData and make sure it doesn't have the property lastModified since it will be modified by the update operator $currentDate:

```
...
// remove any property that will be used by update operators
if (newData && newData.hasOwnProperty('lastModified')) {
    delete newData['lastModified'];
}

let result = await database.collection(collection).updateOne(filter, {
            $set: newData,
            $currentDate: {'lastModified': true}
        });
...
```

**Mongodb Error code 40**

The error code 40 refers to 'ConflictingUpdateOperators', which is a conflict of a property in an update operator. In this case it conflicted with another property in the $set so if this happens to anyone check that you are not updating the same property twice in the same command.

The complete [Mongodb Error Code List is available here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/base/error_codes.err) but apparently no official documentation on the description or issues on these codes (apparently was removed with [this commit](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/commit/1ec5c559236e4a975de7f3bfd7a1a0759f1e8e33)).

This solved the issue.
thanks to @Greg for pointing out the right direction.